# Do you take into consideration DialUp connections still?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a web application that has a lot to download (javascript, images, videos, etc), and I was wondering how many people still consider dial up while developing large web applications?

Is there a rule of thumb that you use to determine the individual page sizes? (i.e. home page must be less than 200k)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that today's dial-up is now the phone/mobile market! Making your pages faster to load is better for every user.

Comment: Although phones are usually faster than dialup, speed is still an issue. Not to mention layout design to support phones should be address too (not that it was ever mentioned in the question).

Comment: It is a good point, but as my site is relying on flash at the moment, phone support is not required.

Comment: Phone support's not required because you're using Flash, or you're using Flash because phone support's not required?

Comment: Phones are not supported because we're using flash.

Answer (score 2):

No.  But I try to limit the amount of material to only what is necessary.  Typically use PNGs for images and keep the images to only what is necessary.  I also use (for production) minified JS, compression, etc. Most of my apps are intranet apps and are accessed using the company network, though, so YMMV.

You might want to think about using the [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) extension for Firefox to help minimize your page load time.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the website, Content Sites, Yea, I still think of website payload. 
( maybe not modem speeds, but definitely payload management for Landing Pages / Homepages )

Business to Business, not really, as I am assuming most business looking at my sites are on at least DSL.

You need to see what you 90-95% user base and do your requirements around that, but speed should always be kept in mind.

(Yahoo's ySlow has been a great asset );

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only for clients that pay us to and/or intend to market to mobile platforms.  We typically follow a few common practices such as those that yslow is big on like fewer css files, JS at the bottom of the page, gzipping, etc.

We also use compound css sprites such as what Google and many others do

[image: Google's search page sprite]

which reduces multiple palette overhead and http connections, and solves some caching issues for image intensive sites.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your user base.  If you determine that a large portion of the people you wish to use your product have dial up, or you wish for everybody to use it, then you have to take it into account.

However, if you only want to hit a very niche audience who you know are broadband enabled, you can take a few more liberties.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should strive for the fastest possible loading times. If this means minifying your code or making other such improvements then that's okay. In general I try to use file formats that are more compressed for faster loading times.

Do I explicitly think about dial-up users? No, not really.